# Regex/Java. Match words with 'aa' sequence

Tags: java, regex, contains

Hi im looking for a regex command for matching words with only 2 letters 'a' or 'A'. Single 'a' is ok but when word contains 3 or more 'a' next to each other its wrong.

G**AA**SSCC - good 
EAAASCS - bad 
AAASD**AA** - **bad** 
ASBS**AA** - good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for the not of `aaa` before matching each single character. This could be done through negative lookahead assertion.

```
String line[] = {"GAASSCC", "EAAASCS", "AAASDAA", "ASBSAA" };
for (String i : line)
    if(i.matches("(?i)^(?:(?!aaa).)*?(?<!a)aa(?!a).*"))
    {
        System.out.println(i +" -> Good");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(i +" -> Bad");
    }
```

**Output:**

```
GAASSCC -> Good
EAAASCS -> Bad
AAASDAA -> Bad
ASBSAA -> Good
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?i)` called case-insensitive modifier. This makes the regex to match both upper and lowercase letters.
- `^` Asserts that we are at the start.
- `(?:(?!aaa).)*?` Here comes the tricky part. This check for the not of `aaa` at  the first. If there is no `a` which isn't followed by a two `a` characters then only the corresponding character would be matched.
- `(?<!a)` This asserts the string we are going to match won't be preceded by a character `a`
- `aa` Matches the string `aa`
- `(?!a)` Negative lookahead which asserts that the match won't be followed by the character `a`

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out all words with at least 3 A's in a row with this:

```
\b\w*[aA]{3,}\w*\b
```

Explanation:

`\b`: Word boundary. Basically, the start or end of a word.

`\w*`: Any number of letters. So zero or more.

`[aA]`: Either a or A

`{3,}`: Three or more times the preceding element (`[aA]`)

So this finds all words that have at least three A's in a row, surrounded by any number of other letters.

If you then want to find words that contain one or two A's in sequence, you can adapt the above to `\b\w*[aA]{1, 2}\w*\b`. In fact, you could also use `\b\w*[aA]+\w*\b`, since you have already filtered out words with three or more A's.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
[^aA]*[aA]{2}[^aA]*
```